# not evaluated the negative value(-1) correctly with filter in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

i'm trying to fiter value with ng-repeat in angularJS.
but when the filtered object is negative value (ex.-1),  it is evalueated as pogitive value(ex.1).

html :

```
<div ng-controller="tagCtrl">
    <h5>filter object</h5>
    <li ng-repeat="cat in categoryToFilter()|filter: filterCategories" >
       <span class="cateNm">{{cat.catNm}}</span>
       <span ng-repeat="tag in tagCount|filter:{catId : cat.catId}">{{tag.tagNm}}|</span>
    </li>
</div>
```

js :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
function tagCtrl($scope){
$scope.tagCount = [
    {catId:-1, catNm:"nagativeCategory", tagId:0, tagNm:"Z", count:50},
    {catId:1, catNm:"aCategory", tagId:1, tagNm:"A", count:50},
    {catId:2, catNm:"bCategory", tagId:2, tagNm:"B", count:30},
    {catId:3, catNm:"cCategory", tagId:3, tagNm:"C", count:20}
];

var indexedCategories = [];
$scope.categoryToFilter = function(){
    indexedCategories = [];
    return $scope.tagCount;
};

$scope.filterCategories = function(cat){
    var cateIsNew = indexedCategories.indexOf(cat.catId) == -1;
    if(cateIsNew){
        indexedCategories.push(cat.catId);
    }
    return cateIsNew;
};
}
```

output(Incorrect） :

> nagativeCategory Z| 
> aCategory Z|A| 
> bCategory B|
> cCategory C|

'Z' ｓhould not be included in aCategory.
How can I filter negative value correctlly ?

thanks in advance.

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/xVjw6/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, angular uses `contain` operator for the filter.

Try `true` as the 2rd parameter to use `angular.equals` to compare

```
filter:{catId : cat.catId}:true
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UyfRw/1/)

From [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter):

> true: A shorthand for `function(actual, expected) { 
>                      return angular.equals(expected,actual)
>                   }`.
>   this is essentially strict comparison of expected and actual.

Comment: I use this site for first time. i accepted your answer. thanks.